# Shiny: Storing text input into a variable conditional on selection from a drawdown box

Tags: shiny, reactive-programming, textinput

I have the following problem (and for quite some time I am not able to solve it). I am trying to store a text input corresponding to e.g. "option 1" from a drop-down into a variable (in userEnv). Next, I want to change the selection in the drop-down, to e.g. "option 2" and again retrieve the text to a variable and store, etc.

I am attaching my codes for server.R and ui.R below.

Can anyone advise me, please, on what should I do in order to keep the text input saved in the userEnv, even after I choose another to option. Also, I would like to be able to review my inputs after being typed in.

Thx a bunch!

**A) server.R:**

```
     library(shiny)
     shinyServer(function(input, output) {

     userEnv <- new.env()
     userEnv$text <- NULL

  optionID <- reactive({
    isolate({print("inside reactive")})
    if(is.null(input$SELoption)){return(NULL)}
    return(input$SELoption)
  })

  observe({
    fID <- optionID()

    isolate({print("inside observe")})
    isolate({print(paste0("fID: ", fID))})

    if(!is.null(userEnv$text[[fID]])) updateTextInput(session, "text", value = userEnv$text[[fID]])
    isolate({print(paste0("input$text: ", input$text))})

  })

})
```

**B) ui.R:**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('SELoption', label = "Select option", 
                choices = c(
                  "Option 1" = 'f1',
                  "Option 2" = 'f2',
                  "Option 3" = 'f3'),
                selected = 'f1')
  ),

  mainPanel(
    textInput("text", label = strong("Text"), value = 0)
  )
))
```

Comment: It is probably easier to have three textInput. It is possible to do what you want to do now, but will not be very clear to the user.

Comment: @warmoverflow Well, I cannot have 3 textInputs, as each of them needs to be on the conditional panel, otherwise it would be confusing for the user. Isn't there some way to achieve exactly what I want?

Comment: I don't see why you cannot have three textInputs. You can add an `actionButton` and set your server code to be conditional on the actionButton (use `observeEvent`).